# Returning a value from a data factory pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need to get a value returned from a pipeline.

Scenario:
I am connecting to an API for data.
The api needs a token thats generated at the start of the data pipeline.
Tokens have a short life and if they expire need to be renewed.

Rather than have multiple web activities to renew the token all over the place, i want just one pipeline that gets the token and returns it. the pipeline can be called where needed.
As the web call to get a token takes a lot of parameters, if i ever have to change it, it would be easier change it in one place than many.

So far i have not seen a way to do this easily in ADF using parameters or variables and would appreciate any expertise.

Thanks!

Comment: Pipeline do not return data, you would have to write the data to an interim store. This scenario sounds like a great use case for an Azure Function.

Answer (score 0):

As @Joel Cochran mentioned in the comments, currently the pipeline will not return any output. You can raise a feature request from the Azure data factory.

Below are the alternative methods you can use to get the output of child pipeline.

***Method1:***

You can call your pipeline from another pipeline using Execute pipeline activity, but this will not return the actual output of the child pipeline, instead returns the child pipeline RunId.

Using this pipelineRunID, you can make a call using web activity to get the [activity run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/activity-runs/query-by-pipeline-run#activityruns_querybypipelinerun) details which contain the actual output of the pipeline in the response body.

**Example:**

1. Execute child pipeline from parent pipeline using `Execute pipeline` activity to get the pipeline RunId.

[image]

2. Make a POST request to get the activity runs using the `web` activity by adding a dynamic expression in the URL to the get child pipeline RunId to include in the HTTP request.

**URL:**

```
@concat('https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{your subscription ID}/resourceGroups/{your resource group name}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{your factory name}/pipelineruns/',string(activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineRunId),'/queryActivityruns?api-version=2018-06-01')
```

[image]

3. You can use the output of the child pipeline from the response body of the `web` activity in later activities.

`@string(activity('Web1').output.value[0].output)`

***Method2:***

You can store the output in a storage or a database and retrieve it again using lookup activity from another pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly set a global variable as well.
Global variables are defined from Manage / Global Parameters  menu.

Answer (score 0):

It's now possible to return a value from a Pipeline. the Feature is in preview. For more info, have a look at the below article.

https://praveenkumarsreeram.com/2023/02/15/azure-data-factory-return-value-from-a-child-pipeline-to-a-parent-pipeline/

Answer (score 0):

You could take the pipeline output, and passed to whatever pipe you want. It's the way pipeline share information.

Look at this pipeline's output

[image]

Then, I use its output in other pipeline.

[image]

I hope It may help you